# Implementing drawer (Offcanvas) in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement Drawer (Offcanvas) component in react, so here the requirement is, there will be one Drawer whose component will change dynamically, consider something like bootstrap modal, you have one modal but you can trigger that modal from anywhere from the page just write `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalid"`, but implementing this in react requires communicating between 2 root components & setting drawers component data from the triggering component or button. I have seen people added trigger & modal in same component & than passing `state.toggle` flag like below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
        <Drawer isOpen={this.state.drawer} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <DrawerBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </DrawerBody>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But in my case, there is no relationship between components, this component `<Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>` will be added in multiple places & there is no coupling between `Drawer` & `Button`. So how I can achieve this without using any state management like Redux or Flux or anything else

Comment: In your case, pubsub might be a good option if you don't want to use any state management and the components are independent. you can publish events from one component and subscribe to that event in another component and add your logic based on the event type. Still not sure about your actual problem but this might be something you are looking for. link: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js`

Comment: @Sid I have seen this, but then I have to implement dynamic events because see I work in a middle of designer and developer, I create different components like button, form fields, modal, drawer & then developers can use it, so here I can't add static events.